# Have system not call keyPressed in my class that extends class that implements KeyListener

Tags: java

Let's say I have a class `MyKeyListener` that implements `java.awt.event.KeyListener`, meaning it has a method:

```
public void keyPressed(java.awt.event.KeyEvent keyEvent) {}
```

Now I want to maky myself another class `MyFrameworkClass` that extends `MyKeyListener` but kinda overrides the `keyPressed()` method.

```
public void keyPressed(int keyCode) {}
```

Obviously this won't work, since the system calls `keyPressed` with a `java.awt.event.KeyEvent` object, but I'm now asking for an `int`.

If my `keyPressed(int keyCode)` was renaned to e.g. `myKeyPressed(int keyCode)`, then my problem would be solved. Then I could do something like this in `MyKeyListener` class:

```
public void keyPressed(java.awt.event.KeyEvent keyEvent) {
 myKeyPressed(keyEvent.getKeyCode());
}

public void abstract myKeyPressed(int keyCode);
```

My question: Is there any way I can do that while keeping the same name for both methods?
Meaning, have the system call the `keyPressed()` in class `MyKeyListener` rather than the one in `MyFrameworkClass` despite the fact that I'm extending `MyKeyListener` (because I want to manually call the one in `MyFrameworkClass` from `MyKeyListener`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right on track there.
Two methods with separate signatures (In your case, parameter list) are treated as different methods.

You could implement your idea like this:

```
package test;

import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyListener;

import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class MyFramework {
    static class MyKeyListener implements KeyListener {
        @Override
        public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
            keyPressed(e.getKeyCode());
        }
        public void keyPressed(int keyCode) {}

        @Override public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) { }
        @Override public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) { }
    }

    static class MyFrameworkClass extends MyKeyListener {
        @Override
        public void keyPressed(int keyCode) {
            System.out.println(String.format("Key pressed: '%d'", keyCode));
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame jFrame = new JFrame("Framework test");
        jFrame.setSize(200, 200);
        jFrame.addKeyListener(new MyFrameworkClass());
        jFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        jFrame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Your answer is not quite how I ended up doing it, but it helped a lot.